# Global Symbol requires package name while using "my" in Sub

Tags: perl, global-variables, subroutine

I have a class where we are learning Perl so forgive me if I made a simple/obvious error as I am still learning. My question is why do I get the error

> Global Symbol "%localhash" requires explicit package name

as well as the same error for "$param" when I do declare it with "my %localhash" the first time inside the Sub.

My code for reference:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter;
use vars qw(@ISA @EXPORT);

@ISA=qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT=("insert_user", "modify_user", "remove_user", "generate_list");


#Insert user Function
Sub insert_user{
    my $param = shift;
    my %localhash = %$param;
    print "Please enter Username: ";
    my $user_name = <>;
    chomp($user_name);
    if(exists ($localhash{$user_name})){ 
        print "Error, user already exists!";
        last;
    }
    $user_name =~ s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g;
    $user_name = lc($user_name);
    $localhash{$user_name};
    return %localhash;
    print "Please enter a password: ";
    my $user_password = <>;
    %localhash{$user_name} = $user_password;
    return %localhash;
}
```

In my class we are suppose to use "my $param" and "my %localhash" various times so I would repeat the same process in declaring "my" in every Sub but I keep getting the same error as if the "my" is not there.

Comment: `%localhash{$user_name} = $user_password;` - this line should be `$localhash{$user_name}`, no? And why do you basically break the code with than `return %localhash;` in the middle of it? )

Comment: and you shouldn't use last outside a loop

Comment: I am unsure about that, I followed my professor for that line. Not sure if he made a mistake or if I followed incorrectly there but I dont think I got an error for that.

Comment: @ysth I will be calling this subroutine inside a loop from my main Perl file, is this format still fine if I want it to exit the loop if user does not exist?

Comment: @RobertRodriguez: that will work, but is a very bad idea and so gives a warning;  to suppress the warning, do `if (...) { print "Error, user already exists!"; no warnings 'exiting'; last; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *first* error you get is `syntax error at foo.pl line 13, near "my "`; getting a syntax error throws perl's parser off and you will often get spurious errors afterwards due to it not having successfully recognized a declaration or being mistaken about scope.  Ignore them and fix the syntax error (which in this case is actually a couple lines earlier: `Sub` instead of `sub`, as pointed out by toolic).  That will get you on to the next error :)

Other comments:

Using `last` as you do is bad; it will exit a loop, but there isn't a loop in your code.  If your sub is called from within a loop, it will (with a warning) exit your sub and exit *that* loop, but that is the kind of action at a distance that leads to bugs.

For a long time, Exporter hasn't needed to be subclassed; simply `use Exporter 'import';` instead of setting `@ISA`.

Comment: Thank you guys so much! Yes, the problem was that since it was Sub rather than sub and not continuing on, also found a few more little errors thanks to fixing this. Thank you again.

Comment: In that case what would be my best bet to have the program restart should the `if(exists ($localhash{$user_name}))` = true?

Comment: I would probably make it just do `return;` and in the caller, do something like `%user = insert_user(...) or last;`

Comment: Thank you very much once again, I just realized with what you said that the `return %localhash;` is what that is for.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the issue with `Sub`, you have `%localhash{$user_name}` instead of `$localhash{$user_name}`; you check whether your user name already exists
*before* you strip non-alphanumeric characters and lower-case it, which is wrong; and you fail to `chomp` the password. You also have very little blank space, which can make a program much more readable

This is something like what I would write

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter qw/ import /;

our @EXPORT = qw/ insert_user modify_user remove_user generate_list /;

sub insert_user {
    my ($param)   = @_;
    my %localhash = %$param;

    print "Please enter user name: ";
    my $user = <>;
    chomp $user;

    $user =~ s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g;
    $user = lc $user;
    if ( exists $localhash{$user} ) {
        warn "Error, user already exists!";
        return;
    }

    print "Please enter a password: ";
    my $pass = <>;
    chomp $pass;
    $localhash{$user} = $pass;

    return %localhash;
}
```